# Do two 1D Rectangular Potential Barriers have Bound States?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212568/coefficients-of-wave-function-inside-rectangular-potential-barrier) had me thinking about the related 1D problem of two rectangular potential barriers:

[image: Two rectangular potential barriers.]

The potential is *zero* everywhere but for the two barriers, where it is $V_0$.

As ever I am interested in possible bound states for particles with energy $E<V_0$.

The problem is reminiscent of [this model of $\alpha$ decay](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuclear/alptun2.html) of $\text{Po-212}$.

Also, if $|b| \to \infty$ then the problem becomes that of the *finite potential* well where bound states are possible. This suggests that for large $|b|$ bound states may be found.

And for a particle with $E<V_0$ incoming from the left one can see how it would first be part reflected/part transmitted at $x=-b$, then its amplitude reduced between $-b<x<-a$ and then it would undergo symmetric treatment at the right hand potential barrier. This of course would suggest no bound states.

Does anyone know the definitive answer?

Answer (score 2):

THere are no bound states.  You've pretty much answered your own question.

Imagine what the lowest energy bound state would look like:  an upside-down bell-shaped curve.  This will match to exponentials in the forbidden region.  But exponentials never go to zero.  At $b$ the exponentials have to mate to *something*:  they will mate to sinusoids extending to infinity.

Comment: Does this mean we shouldn't consider an $\alpha$ particle in a Po-212 as a bound particle either?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not a bound state.  But Po-212 will remain Po-212 until it's not.  :)

Comment: If it were a bound state, it wouldn't decay - it is a metastable state with a lower energy state available by having an alpha 'decide' it is time to be somewhere else (i.e. the wave function outside of the barriers).

Comment: @garyp: does it have to be "an upside-down bell-shaped curve"? If $\psi$ is a solution of the SE, then so is so is $-\psi$, no?

Comment: $-\psi = \psi e^{i\pi}$, a global phase shift.  Perfectly good. I was just focusing on the essentials for the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the book *Molecular Electronics*, by Cuevas and Scheer, Sec. 4.3, there should be bound states. You can have resonant tunneling in the transmission probability located at the energies of those bound states.

Check for example [this](http://nano-bio.ehu.es/files/Resonant_tunneling-Laresgoiti.pdf). Ok, there is no strictly a bound state, but a quasi-bound state which is in between the barriers bouncing around.